Spring/Hibernage shares the persistence context from before the transaction with the transaction
In the following example, when the POST /foo/test1 endpoint is called, the entity will be saved to the database. However, calling POST /foo/test2 will not trigger any updates.
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/foo")
public class FooController {

    @Autowired
    BarService barService;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @PostMapping("/test1")
    public void post1() {
        System.out.println("\n".repeat(10));
        FileEntity fileEntity = entityManager.find(FileEntity.class, 2L);
        fileEntity.setDescription(fileEntity.getDescription() + "-1");
        barService.bar();
    }

    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.SUPPORTS)
    @PostMapping("/test2")
    public void post2() {
        System.out.println("\n".repeat(10));
        FileEntity fileEntity = entityManager.find(FileEntity.class, 2L);
        fileEntity.setDescription(fileEntity.getDescription() + "-1");
        barService.bar();
    }
}




@Service
public class BarService {
    @Transactional(Transactional.TxType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("log");
    }
}

I expect that no updates occur in either call

This is a container issue, not JPA - what container is managing your transactions?

@Chris I am using Spring Boot 3.2

You might want to tag this question to those forums
